# Regex to extract the string after a number in R

Tags: r, string

I want to extract the string after a number using RegEx in R. For example in this vector:

```
ex <- c("1112 - 6839 COLBORNE ST", "11 - 5552 FRONTENACK ST", "1430 WINDFIELD CRES LINE", "111 - 55502 FRONT ST SOUTH WEST")
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
COLBORNE, FRONTENACK, WINDFIELD, FRONT
```

I know that in Python this can be implemented through capturing groups but I was not able to do it in R or maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
Credits to akrun:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(ex, "(?<=\\d\\s{0,2})[A-Za-z]+\\b")
```

**First answer:**

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(ex, "[a-zA-Z]+")
```

```
[1] "COLBORNE"   "FRONTENACK" "WINDFIELD"  "FRONT"
```

Comment: If the OP's condition needs to be met (though it works in this examples) `str_extract(ex, "(?<=\\d\\s{0,2})[A-Za-z]+\\b")#
[1] "COLBORNE"   "FRONTENACK" "WINDFIELD"  "FRONT"`